# Nested for loop is not working

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the price data of a property company's website - SRX for my school's assignment. However, my `for-loop` does not seem to be working. I can only manage to obtain the first iteration of the loop `(j = 1)`, and `j` does not run to 2,3,4 and 5. Any ideas why? Have tried searching but couldn't find or understand available explanations. Thank you.

```
library(rvest)

scrape <- function() {
  for (i in 1:20) {
    child1 <- html_children(listing)
    child2 <- html_children(child1[i+1])
    child3 <- html_children(child2[2])
    #getting to the layer of price
    price <- html_text(child3[3])
    print(price)
  }
}

for (j in 1:5) {  
  url <- paste("https://www.srx.com.sg/search/sale/residential?page=", j, sep = "")
  srx <- read_html(url)
  listing <- html_nodes(srx, ".listing-box")
  scrape()
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are only getting the fifth iteration. In each run of the `j` loop you are overwriting the `url`, `srx` and `listing` variable.

Comment: Changing the third line to `for (i in 1:19)`  runs, but may not get all the prices. There must be something different about the 20th node.

Comment: ... its not just the 20th item. You are not grabbing the correct nodes. `for (i in 1:3)` gives
 [1] "$2,890,000"
[1] ""
[1] "$1,956,150"
which is incorrect. There is an extra empty item.